# How to use native code like c/c++/objective c in my android application?

Tags: android

Friends,I want to work on a OpenGL application, in which i have to develop a globe which includes the functionality to show the details of a country when i will touch any part of the globe.. for this i need to first develop a globe, But To design and adding functionality to a globe i have to use c/c++/Objective c language.So now the question is Can i use c/c++/objective c code in my application?What will be the solution? i have also researched much to get a globe in which i can add some functionality, But i didn't get. If any one have any solution let me know .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can program for android in native code (C/C++/etc).  Take a look at the android NDK and JNI for more information.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Now, last time I used android, the native code did not support touch inputs (this may have changed in later versions).  So if you want the user to be able to touch the screen to make your globe spin around, you will need to make a java wrapper to translate the API calls to your native code.

Answer (score 0):

Look on Android NDK (Native Development Kit) :

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html